# How can I force a child class to use parent methods when it overrides some of them locally?

Tags: java, inheritance, setter, overriding

So, here's the problem. Suppose I have the following code flow:

```
public class SomeGrandparent {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    ...
    public void setX(int x) {setting value of x...}
    public void setY(int y) {setting value of y...}
}

public class SomeParent extends SomeGrandparent {
    ...
    public void move() {manipulate object movement via calls to inherited setX and setY}
}

public class SomeChild extends SomeParent {
    ...
    public void setX(int x) {throw exception} //Override method. Child should not be allowed to directly modify X.
    public void setY(int y) {throw exception} //Override method. Child should not be allowed to directly modify Y.
}
```

Then, later in the program, I have the following:

```
SomeChild aChild = new SomeChild();
...
aChild.move();
```

Upon execution, when `aChild.move()` is called, errors are thrown. Why is it that, in `SomeChild`, the inherited `move()` method is using the local overridden setX and setY methods? Is there some way I can have `aChild.move()` call the move() defined in SomeParent AND use the setX and setY defined in SomeParent as well?

Even if I have the following explicitly defined in SomeChild,

```
...
public void move() {
    super.move();
}
```

then `aChild.move()` still utilizes the local overridden setX and setY in `SomeChild`. This is driving me nuts. Any help appreciated.

The only solution I can fathom is to copy all the code from SomeParent's `move()` method and paste it into SomeChild, replacing all its references to setX and setY with super.setX and super.setY. However, this completely defeats the purpose of inheritance to begin with!

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Why are you overriding methods in the child if you don't plan on allowing he child to use them? If you want to _force_ implementation of a method, declare it `abstract` if you want to _prevent_ overriding, declare the method `final`

Comment: @RyanJ : If you don't override the setters in the child class, how else can you prevent someone else's code from calling aChild.setX(50), for example? I was taught in my Java class that a common way to restrict access is to override the setters. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism will choose the runtime type of the object for calls to `setX` and `setY` even if they are called in a superclass that doesn't override those methods.

You can make the methods `setX()` and `setY` `final` in `SomeGrandparent` so that subclasses such as `SomeChild` can't override them.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is a typo in your code example and that you are making use of Polymorphism, so your real code is something like:

```
SomeGrandparent aChild = new SomeChild();
```

And not what you said:

```
SomeChild aChild = new SomeChild();
```

Which justify your both issues:

- You are getting compiler error when `aChild.move()` is called because `move()` doesn't exist in `SomeGrandparent`
- You are using `setX`  and `setY` of `SomeChild` because of their Object's runtime Type as explained per rgettman's answer